# is it a array or object we creating in this line? I want to know the meaning of this line used in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is it a array or object we creating in this line? I want to know the meaning of this line used in Javascript ?

```
document.getElementById("status").options[1]=new Option("OPEN","open");
```

I am using this for my Dynamic dropdown list

Comment: Object. Though array is also an object, my guess is it will create an object of type *HTMLOptionElement*. If you wish to be sure, you can check a variable is an array using `Array.isArray` and for object, you can either check using `typeof`. To know what kind of object it is, try `obj.constructor.name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code line you posted is creating a new [Option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option) **object**, with the value `open` and the text `OPEN`, and adding it to the options list (which is an array), in the 2nd position, of a HTML dropdown list ([`select`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp)) element called `status`.

`document.getElementById("status")` Returns the HTML [`select`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) element.

`.options[1]=` Sets the select element's 2nd option element (the index starts at `0`).

`new Option("OPEN","open")` Creates the new [Option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option) **object** with value `open` and text `OPEN`.

Comment: okk so there is any difference, why there is an options and for object we used Option, I mean not adding 's' at the end.

Comment: It's for 1 specific option, and not for the options list as a list - @Vinodthapa

Answer (score 0):

It is adding the newly created [HTMLOptionElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option) object to the select's option collection which is an array-like construct

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the [**Option() Constructor** MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option) you will see that, it's used to create a [HTMLOptionElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement).

Where the first param is the `textContent` of the `<option>` and the second param is its `value`.

So writing `new Option("OPEN","open")` will create the following HTML option:

```
<option value="open">OPEN</option>
```

And to answer your question *Is it a array or object we creating in this line?*:

It will **create** a new `object`of type [`HTMLOptionElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement) and **add** it to your dropdown `options` collection.

Answer (score 0):

This is part of WebAPI of HTML. There is a HTMLOptionElement interface represents  elements and inherits all classes and methods of the HTMLElement interface.

> HTMLOptionElement.option() Is a constructor creating an
>   HTMLOptionElement object

**Syntax**

> var optionElementReference = new Option(text, value, defaultSelected,
>   selected);

**text**

> text is Optional. The content of the element, i.e. the displayed text.
>   The default value is "".

**value: Optional**

> It is the value attribute of the equivalent . If this is not
>   specified, the value of text is used as the value.

**defaultSelected: default value is Optional**

> A Boolean that sets the selected attribute value, i.e. so that this
>    will be the default value selected in the  element
>   when the page is first loaded. If there is no value set then set as
>   false.

**selected: default value is Optional**

> A Boolean that sets the option's selected state; the default is false
>   (not selected). If omitted, even if the defaultSelected argument is
>   true, the option is not selected.

Reference taken from

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option

https://www.electrictoolbox.com/javascript-add-options-html-select/